# How can I fix this PHP error after manually updating WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, self-updating

After manually updating WordPress, HTTP Error 500 appeared. I configured PHP directives and these errors showed up

> Warning:
> require(/home/vol6_7/epizy.com/epiz_30806720/htdocs/wp-includes/version.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /home/vol6_7/epizy.com/epiz_30806720/htdocs/wp-settings.php on line 33
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
> '/home/vol6_7/epizy.com/epiz_30806720/htdocs/wp-includes/version.php'
> (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear/') in
> /home/vol6_7/epizy.com/epiz_30806720/htdocs/wp-settings.php on line 33

This is what line 32-34 contains.

```
global $wp_version, $wp_db_version, $tinymce_version, $required_php_version, $required_mysql_version, $wp_local_package;
require ABSPATH . WPINC . '/version.php';
require ABSPATH . WPINC . '/load.php';
```

While *version.php* doesn't exists in */htdocs/wp-includes/*

Comment: How did you upgrade WP? Did you also update the `wp-settings.php`-file? And from what version to which version? Please add more details/specifics to your question.

Comment: Hello. Sorry. I updated from 5.8.3 to 5.9. I deleted everything in htdocs except wp-content and wp-config as per the instruction. After that, I put all the files from the WordPress package except the wp-content and wp-config

Comment: /wp-includes/ should include version.php file. Please download fresh copy of same wordpress version and replace existing wp-includes folder. Error occurred was due to missing of required files

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I retransferred all the files and now my site is back. Thanks! That's so dumb of me lol

Comment: For what it's worth, the WordPress developers put a *lot* of testing effort into their automated upgrade procedure. May as well use their work by avoiding manual upgrades.